# How can you unit test Apache Cache Timer routes?

Tags: junit, apache-camel

Using Apache Camel 2.9.1

How do I unit test something like the following?

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

         from("timer.something?delay=0?repeatCount=1")
             // do some stuff
             .to("{{some.endpoint}}")
             .end()

         from("timer.somethingelse?delay=3000&period=1000")
             // do some stuff
             .to("{{some.other.endpoint}}")
             .end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is exactly that you want to unit test here? 
Because it's clueless to unit test the timer component (I mean to unit test if it's triggered or not; and if its properties works as it should be): Camel team has done that already.

What is logical to unit test here is the "// do some stuff" part, which you'd do by mocking the endpoints. Your first route will be fired automaticly, while the second will with initial delay. You'll have to wait that much at least to assert anything. In these kind of cases I usually read the endpoint properties from a properties files like

```
from("timer:somethingelse?{{2nd.timer.properties}}")
```

and that can be set to

```
2nd.timer.properties=delay=3000&period=1000 //in prod
2nd.timer.properties=delay=0 //during tests
```

So that one is triggered at startup as well. Hope that helps,

Gergely

Answer (score 2):

You can also use advice with in your unit test, and replace the from endpoint uri in the route during testing, and for example use a direct endpoint, then you can send a message to the direct endpoint to trigger the route to run.

See details at the Camel docs about testing

- http://camel.apache.org/testing
- http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

And there is also NotifyBuilder which can be used for "black box testing" where you may assert that X messages was processed etc

- http://camel.apache.org/notifybuilder.html